# Casting DynamicLabel to Label in Clojure for Neo4j Embedded

Tags: clojure, neo4j, clojure-java-interop

I am trying to rewrite the neo4j sample code located [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.0.1/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4jWithNewIndexing.java) in clojure. But when I try to create a node, I get the following error

```
ClassCastException Cannot cast org.neo4j.graphdb.DynamicLabel to [Lorg.neo4j.graphdb.Label;  java.lang.Class.cast (Class.java:3094)
```

Here is my code:

```
(ns neotest.handler
  (:import (org.neo4j.graphdb
            DynamicLabel
            GraphDatabaseService
            Label
            Node
            ResourceIterator
            Transaction
            factory.GraphDatabaseFactory
            schema.IndexDefinition
            schema.Schema)))

(def db
  (let [path "C:\\Users\\xxx\\code\\neotest\\resources\\db1"]
    (. (new GraphDatabaseFactory) (newEmbeddedDatabase path))))


(defn create-node []
  (try (let [tx (. db beginTx)
             l (. DynamicLabel (label "User"))]
         (. db (createNode l))
         (. tx success))))
```

I have tried type-hinting of all kinds and in all places, and I still get the same error.

Comment: This is happening to me too. I rather think it's a bug. When Clojure converts a function to a method call it typecasts parameters to the types defined in the method signature. This kind of thing is usually a class loader problem: i.e. the Label interface Clojure is casting the DynamicLabel to isn't the "right" one. I've just started on trying to debug this—so far without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the varargs Label... parameter. This was a bit of Clojure/Java interop I didn't know about: you have to pass the parameter in as an array (even if there's only one), so you need to do something like:

```
(. db (createNode (into-array Label [l])))
```

to make it work. There's another afternoon I won't be getting back!

Answer (score 1):

the calls to dynamicLabel in the example java code look like:

```
DynamicLabel.label( "User" )
```

which would translate to:

```
(DynamicLabel/label "user")
```

because label is a static method of the class `org.neo4j.graphdb.DynamicLabel` which has the signature:

```
 static Label   label(String labelName)
```

Comment: I rather think this is the varargs argument of createNode()